# Line chart, show data label inside chart when data is less than min

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to show the data label of all the points that are outside the limits.

I've tried a few things but none works.

In this example it should show the "-15" inside the graphic area.

http://jsfiddle.net/fpanci/4u5zQ/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            marginRight: 50
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 
                   {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            align: 'left',
                            style: {
                                fontWeight: 'bold'
                            },
                            x: 3,
                            y: 10,
                            verticalAlign: 'middle',
                            crop: false
                        },
                        y: -15
                    },
                    161.4,
                    54.4,
                    61.1
                  ]
        }]

    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: The point itself should be outside the graph, but the label inside?

Comment: Limits of chart or any range? in other words, which labels shoudl be printed, because I see that you have only last datalabel enabled.

Comment: @Ondkloss, yes. I have to define limits (ie, min: 0, max: 100) and the points that are outside the limits should be shown as data labels inside it.

Comment: @SebastianBochan, only those that correspond to points outside the limits. Here if the limits are 0 and 200, the points to be shown as datalabes should be -15 and 216.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a point is not visible, it's data label won't be either.

I would set this up as a separate series for the points outside the limits.

`Example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/J5Tbe/